# Scala 2.10, Double.isNaN, and boxing

Tags: scala, boxing, scala-2.10

In Scala 2.10, is `someDouble.isNaN` expected to box? Running my code calling `.isNaN` through a decompiler, I still see telltale calls to `double2Double` in my code. Given the new `AnyVal` work in 2.10, I'd expect it to be no worse than `java.lang.Double.isNaN(someDouble)` at runtime with no spurious allocations. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, `isNaN` is a method on `java.lang.Double`, and it is essential to have an implicit conversion to `java.lang.Double`, so the Scala `RichDouble` value class cannot reimplement `isNaN` to be fast, and when you use `isNaN` you box to `java.lang.Double`.

Since this leaves only slow or awkward ways to test for `NaN`, I define

```
implicit class RicherDouble(val d: Double) extends AnyVal {
  def nan = java.lang.Double.isNaN(d)
}
```

and then I can just use `.nan` to check.

Comment: Why should this be any faster than boxing the double?

Comment: @gzm0 - Because this "boxes" to a value class (that's the `extends AnyVal` part), which isn't actually created unless you need to pass it as an object or generic or put it in an array.  If you just use it (like you are here), Scala emits bytecode that is just a method call, since there's actually nothing that requires a real object to exist.

Comment: Couldn't there be a higher-priority implicit to your `RicherDouble`, with the same `isNaN` name on it? Or if not, something of the same priority to fail with ambiguity to remind yourself not to use that method in tight loops.

Comment: @MyseriousDan - I do actually define the `isNaN` method also to get an ambiguous implicit conversion warning.  As for making it higher priority, you can't do that without changing the library, and I'm not sure whether the necessary change would break anything.

Comment: @RexKerr Nice. Missed the `AnyVal` there.

Comment: @RexKerr do you have any particular possible breakage in mind? I could fix this with an additional layer of predef pastry.

Comment: @extempore - I don't, I'm just extremely wary of moving priorities around in something so incredibly heavily used.